# Split Numbers within parenthesis in Java

Tags: java, string, split, numbers

I would like to split this input: `12132002(177) 012(207.5) 014(184)` into two arrays, like this:
`num[500] = 12132002,012,014, etc.`
and 
`mark[500] = 177,207.5,184, etc.`

The Fact is that I'm accepting values from user like this, where i don't know the total number which he/she will input.

How can I code in Java that kind of splitting? Is it like this?

```
int number[500];
for(int i=0;i<500;i++) {
    number=num.split("//(");
}
```

Comment: `int` can't handle floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To code "that kind of splitting", you will have to:

1. Declare your variables: `String[] number`, `String[] mark`, `String num`, and `String[] numSplit`.
2. Split `num` by `" "` (spaces). Assign this to `numSplit`.
3. Loop through `numSplit` from `0` to `numSplit.length` with `i`.
4. Set `number[i]` to `numSplit[i]` from the beginning to the first occurrence of a `"("`.
5. Set `mark[i]` to `numSplit[i]` from one character after the first occurrence of `"("` to one character before the end.
6. Output `number` and `mark`

The full code:

```
String[] number = new String[500]; //1
String[] mark = new String[500];
String num = "12132002(177) 012(207.5) 014(184)";
String[] numSplit = num.split(" "); //2

for(int i = 0; i < numSplit.length; i++) { //3
    number[i] = numSplit[i].substring(0, numSplit[i].indexOf("(")); //4
    mark[i] = numSplit[i].substring(numSplit[i].indexOf("(") + 1, numSplit[i].length() - 1); //5
}

for(int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) System.out.println(number[i]); //6
for(int i = 0; i < mark.length; i++)  System.out.println(mark[i]);
```

Which outputs:

```
12132002
012
014
null (x497)
177
207.5
184
null (x497)
```

Notice that `number`, `mark`, and `numSplit` are `String` arrays because the leading zeros would be cut off in not otherwise. If you don't mind the leading zeros being cut off then you can change `num` to an `int` array and `mark` to a `double` array (Because of the decimal in `207.5`).

Comment: Yeah I was confused when I saw that answer actually I have to add it to a server so can't add like this indeed..

Comment: I'm accepting num like this                                                                          int num = Integer.parseInt(no.getText().trim());                      here in this code String[] numSplit = num.split(" "); //2                this makes me an error @MasterBlaster

Answer (score 1):

Ok buddy, this could be a solution for your problem. I chose to use the methods I have already created for some other project, but I think those can fit for this purpose as well, instead of using some complex REGEX expression. The output is good, though you have to figure out the way you want to store num and mark variables (I suggest arrays). Hope I helped.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "12132002(177)012(207.5)014(184)";

        // output 12132002,012,014 && 177,207.5,184
        // it works good with this string as well -> s = "12132002(177)012(207.5)014(184)111(024)";
        int numOfParanthesis = numOfParanthesis(s, '(');
        String num = "";
        String mark = "";
        // array which contains positions of (
        int[] indexesOpening = indexes(s, '(');
        // array which contains positions of )
        int[] indexesClosing = indexes(s, ')');
        // logic
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfParanthesis; i++){
            if(i == 0){ 
                num = s.substring(i, indexesOpening[i])+",";
                mark = s.substring(indexesOpening[i]+1,indexesClosing[i])+",";

            }else if(i!=numOfParanthesis-1){
                num += s.substring(indexesClosing[i-1]+1, indexesOpening[i])+",";
                mark += s.substring(indexesOpening[i]+1, indexesClosing[i])+",";
            }else{
                num += s.substring(indexesClosing[i-1]+1, indexesOpening[i]);
                mark += s.substring(indexesOpening[i]+1, indexesClosing[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
        System.out.println(mark);
    }

    // returns array of positions for the given character
     public static int[] indexes(String s, char c){
        int numOfParanthesis = numOfParanthesis(s, c);
        int[] indexes = new int[numOfParanthesis];
        int delimetar = s.indexOf(c);
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfParanthesis; i++){
            if(i != -1){
                indexes[i] = delimetar;    
            }
            delimetar = s.indexOf(c, delimetar+1); 
        }
        return indexes;
    } 

    // returns how many times a character repeats in a string
    public static int numOfParanthesis(String s, char c){
        int number = s.indexOf(c);
        int i = 0;
        while (number >= 0){
            number = s.indexOf(c, number+1);
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Guess this is a string since it is a mix of integers 
        // and non-integers, characters like '(', ')' and space. 
        String str = "12132002(177) 012(207.5) 014(184)"; 

        System.out.println("Your string:");
        System.out.println("str=\"" + str + "\"");
        System.out.println();

        // remove all ')' since they will not be used
        // using space as a delimiter is enough
        String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\)", "");

        System.out.println("Your string after removing ')' character:");
        System.out.println("str2=\"" + str2 + "\"");
        System.out.println();

        // Since your input has spaces, we split on spaces
        String[] strings = str2.split("\\s+");

        System.out.println("Result after splitting str2 by spaces:");
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Lets make two array
        String[] num = new String[500];
        String[] mark= new String[500];

        // loop strings
        int cnt = 0;
        for (String s : strings) {
            String[] a = s.split("\\("); // a[0]="012", a[1]="207.5"
            num[cnt] = a[0];
            mark[cnt] = a[1];
            cnt++;
        }

        System.out.println("Result num: ");
        System.out.print("num[500] = ");
        for(String s : num) {
            if(s==null) {break;}
            System.out.print(s + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(" etc.\n");

        System.out.println("Result mark: ");
        System.out.print("mark[500] = ");
        for(String s : mark) {
            if(s==null) {break;}
            System.out.print(s + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(" etc.\n");
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
Your string:
str="12132002(177) 012(207.5) 014(184)"

Your string after removing ')' character:
str2="12132002(177 012(207.5 014(184"

Result after splitting str2 by spaces:
12132002(177
012(207.5
014(184

Result num: 
num[500] = 12132002,012,014, etc.

Result mark: 
mark[500] = 177,207.5,184, etc.
```